# Is the phrase "endemic to the problem" correct?

Tags: word-usage

I heard the phrase "endemic to the problem" used in Marvel's Daredevil as follows:

A: [I could] have a little shop of my own.

B: You got your own office.

A: We have office space. An actual office would involve plantery[sic] and equipment, fax machines or whatever successful people use. (Chuckles) I don't think they use fax machines anymore. How would I know? Which is endemic to the problem.

Is this usage correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, *endemic* means either native to an area or habitat (for flora and fauna).

> The tsetse fly is **endemic** to Africa.

For diseases, it can additionally mean commonly found in a population.

> Hookworm is **endemic** to the poor in Appalachia

I can only guess what was meant by A.  Perhaps "indicative of the problem."

Comment: I believe what was meant was "inherent" to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Disagree. The primary definition applies here. Endemic of the condition, if the condition, is "the problem" applies. The author is saying, "Regularly found among [this] problem".

en·dem·ic enˈdemik/
adjective
1.    (of a disease or condition) regularly found among particular people or in a certain area.